# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Packages' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using .NET entity framework. I am creating a Offer that have Bundle class and that Bundle class have Package and Package Id. I am facing this error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table **'Packages'** when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

while saving my entity into database. The thing that is making me confused is I am getting error related to my Packages entity but I am not adding any entity into Packages.
My Offer class

```
namespace CarWash.Models
{
    public class Offer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Bundle> Bundles { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OfferAddon> OfferAddons { get; set; }

    }

    public class Bundle
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Package Package { get; set; }
        public int PackageId { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
    }

    public class OfferAddon
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Addon Addon { get; set; }
        public int AddonId { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

OfferRequestDto class

```
using CarWash.Models;

namespace CarWash.Dto
{
    public class OfferRequestDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BundleDto> Bundles { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OfferAddonDto> OfferAddons { get; set; }
    }

    public class BundleDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PackageId { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
    }

    public class OfferAddonDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AddonId { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My controller to create offer

```
        [HttpPost("create")]
        public IActionResult CreateOffer([FromBody] OfferRequestDto offer) 
        {
            if(offer == null || !ModelState.IsValid) 
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            var existingOffer = _offerRepository.GetOfferByName(offer.Name);
            if (existingOffer != null) 
            {
                return StatusCode(409, "Offer already exist");
            }
            var offerMap = _mapper.Map<Offer>(offer);
            foreach(var item in offerMap.Bundles)
            {
                var package = _packageRepository.GetPackageById(item.PackageId);
                if (package == null)
                {
                    return NotFound($"Package id {item.PackageId} not found");
                }
                item.Package = package;
                item.PackageId = package.Id;
            }

            foreach(var item in offerMap.OfferAddons)
            {
                var addon = _addonRepository.GetById(item.AddonId);
                if(addon == null)
                {
                    return NotFound($"Add on with id {item.AddonId} is not found");
                }
                item.Addon = addon;
                item.AddonId = addon.Id;
            }

            if (!_offerRepository.CreateOffer(offerMap))
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "Something went wrong while saving");
            }

            return Ok("Offer Created");
        }
```

DataContext

```
using CarWash.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CarWash.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }
        
        public DbSet<Workshop> Workshops { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Package> Packages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Addon> Addons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WorkshopService> WorkshopServices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Offer> Offers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<WorkshopService>()
                .HasKey(ws => new { ws.WorkshopId, ws.ServiceId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<WorkshopService>()
                .HasOne(ws => ws.Workshop)
                .WithMany(w => w.WorkshopServices)
                .HasForeignKey(ws => ws.WorkshopId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<WorkshopService>()
                .HasOne(ws => ws.Service)
                .WithMany(s => s.WorkshopServices)
                .HasForeignKey(ws => ws.ServiceId);
           
        }

    }  
}
```

can you please guide where am i doing mistake?

I am mapping offerRequestDto then getting package by the id that I am getting from response then then assigning it to the OfferMap. Everything looks fine while debugging. But I don't where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Looks like you're doing so right here: `item.PackageId = package.Id;` that goes back into the `offerMap` you are saving.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I added extra line option.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking) in my DbContext injection in program.cs file. and by removing this it is now working fine. builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(option => {
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("sql"));
    //option.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
}
);